# change width and height of UIImageView dynamically inside tableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, xib

I have custom UITableViewCell which made from xib file .
And I have UIImageView inside that cell which I set the fixed width and height and 40x40 and set to hidden

And then in cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource delegate. I check if my datasource for that cell contain a URL to image . If it has ,I set the ImageView to appear .And use SDWebImage to download the image and adjust the size for imageView.frame in the completion block when download complete

Actually, at first appearance it is working fine .I got the ImageView that is the same size and the downloaded image. But if I scroll down and then up to the upper cell again. It just re-appear to 40x40 size gain. Can anyone help ?

This is the code just in case if you are curious.  I guess nothing wrong with the code the problem is how I set the UIImageView in .xib file but I don't know how to solve it.

```
//    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

if([item postImageURLString]){

        void (^completionBlock)(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) = ^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

            CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width/3,cell.frame.size.height -5 -image.size.height, image.size.width, image.size.height);

            [cell.postImageView setFrame:imageFrame];


        };

            [cell.postImageView setHidden:NO];


        [cell.postImageView setImageWithURL:URL completed:completionBlock ];

    }
```

Comment: Show the whole method please. Is there a reason you're resizing the image (how do you guarantee that it won't be bigger than the cell)?

Comment: The reason that I resize because these images are uploaded by users and the size can be varied . I will constraint the width to fit the ios screen . And I will implent HeightForRowAtIndexPath to re-adjust the height of cell later when I solve a current problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has something to do with the tableview reusing cells that have the 40x40 image view. It looks like [SDWebImage will not run your completion block if the image is already cached](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/348), so if the tableview redraws the cell and your image is already cached, it never executes the resizing code. You need to add code to your cellForRowAtIndexPath method that checks to see if the image is already cached, and if it is then resize the image view.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I notice that this is true. The completion block never get called if it is already cached. Anyway, I can't find the way to check if the image is cached. Can you point me to some example ?  Thank you

Comment: I just figured it out. The completion block actually get called. But the problem that the resize is not properly set is because I have autolayout constraint set in .xib file.  Now I remove it and it works just fine.